# vb.net weighbridge scale com port reading live

Tags: vb.net

I have to read my weighbridge scale value to system ,I have created vb.net file for this and  getting reading .but I need live reading and if com port is not detected just get message popup instead of error .Thanks advance for your advice.

```
Imports System. Text
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System. Threading
Imports System. Timers
Imports System.IO
Imports System. Text. RegularExpressions
Imports System. Xml
Imports System. Data

Public Class Form2


  
    Private Sub BtnConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As Eventers) Handles BtnConnect_Click
        txtData.Text = ""
        serialport1 = New Serial Port

        serialport1.PortName = "COM6"
        serialport1.Open()
        serialport1.BaudRate = 9600
        serialport1.Parity = Parity. None
        serialport1.DataBits = 8
        serialport1.StopBits = StopBits.One
        serialport1.DtrEnable = True
        serialport1.RtsEnable = True
        serialport1.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
        serialport1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1
        txtData.Text = Extract Numbers(serialport1.ReadExisting())
            serialport1.Close()

        If serialport1.IsOpen = False Then
            MsgBox("not")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0 ?

Comment: sir this is c# ya , may get same this on vb.net?

Comment: Dim ports As String() = SerialPort.GetPortNames()  For Each port As String In ports

Comment: didn't get your explanation. Could you please give little detailed abt this because i am not much knowledge in those. i am beginner

Comment: Take the code I wrote, paste it into your button click event, add a breakpoint and see what happens at run time.